# C++ safe idiom to call a member function of a class through a shared_ptr class member

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, observer-pattern

#### Problem description

In designing an observer pattern for my code, I encountered the following task: I have a class `Observer` which contains a variable `std::shared_ptr<Receiver>` and I want to use a `weak_ptr<Receiver>` to this shared-pointer to safely call a function `update()` in `Observer` (for a more detailed motivation including some profiling measurements, see the EDIT below).

Here is an example code:

```
struct Receiver
{
    void call_update_in_observer() { /* how to implement this function? */}
};

struct Observer
{
    virtual void update() = 0;
    std::shared_ptr<Receiver> receiver;
};
```

As mentioned there is a `weak_ptr<Receiver>` from which I want to call `Observer::update()` -- at most once -- via `Receiver::call_update_in_observer()`:

```
Observer observer;
std::weak_ptr<Receiver> w (observer.receiver);

auto s = w.lock();
if(s)
{
    s->call_update_in_observer(); //this shall call at most once Observer::update()
                                  //regardless how many copies of observer there are
}
```

(Fyi: the call of `update()` should happen at most once because it updates a `shared_ptr` in some derived class which is the actual observer. However, whether it is called once or more often does not affect the question about "safeness" imo.)

Question:

> - What is an appropriate implementation of `Observer` and `Receiver` to carry out that process in a safe manner?

---

---

#### Solution attempt

Here is an attempt for a minimal implementation -- the idea is that `Receiver` manages a set of currently valid `Observer` objects, of which one member is called:

```
struct Receiver
{
    std::set<Observer *> obs;
    void call_update_in_observer() const
    {
        for(auto& o : obs)
        {
            o->update();
            break;  //one call is sufficient
        }
    }
};
```

The class `Observer` has to take care that the `std::shared_ptr<Receiver>` object is up-to-date:

```
struct Observer
{
    Observer()
    {
        receiver->obs.insert(this);
    }

    Observer(Observer const& other) : receiver(other.receiver)
    {
        receiver->obs.insert(this);
    }

    Observer& operator=(Observer rhs)
    {
        std::swap(*this, rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    ~Observer()
    {
        receiver->obs.erase(this);
    }

    virtual void update() = 0;

    std::shared_ptr<Receiver> receiver = std::make_shared<Receiver>();
};
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/Wdxg0O)

Questions:

> - Is this already safe? -- "safe" meaning that no expired `Foo` object is called. Or are there some pitfalls which have to be
>     considered?
> - If this code is safe, how would one implement the move constructor and assignment?

(I know this has the feeling of being appropriate for CodeReview, but it's rather about a reasonable pattern for this task than about my code, so I posted it here ... and further the move constructors are still missing.)

---

---

#### EDIT: Motivation

As the above requirements have been called "confusing" in the comments (which I can't deny), here is the motivation: Consider a custom `Vector` class which in order to save memory performs shallow copies:

```
struct Vector
{
    auto operator[](int i) const { return v[i]; }
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double> > v;
};
```

Next one has expression template classes e.g. for the sum of two vectors:

```
template<typename _VectorType1, typename _VectorType2>
struct VectorSum
{
    using VectorType1 = std::decay_t<_VectorType1>;
    using VectorType2 = std::decay_t<_VectorType2>;

    //alternative 1: store by value
    VectorType1 v1;
    VectorType2 v2;

    //alternative 2: store by shared_ptr
    std::shared_ptr<VectorType1> v1;
    std::shared_ptr<VectorType2> v2;

    auto operator[](int i) const
    {
        return v1[i] + v2[i];
    }
};

//next overload operator+ etc.
```

According to my measurements, alternative 1 where one stores the vector expressions by value (instead of by shared-pointer) is faster by a factor of two in Visual Studio 2015. In a [simple test on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f52d1f5b285d07c), the speed improvement is even a factor of six:

```
type                      Average access time        ratio
--------------------------------------------------------------
Foo                     : 2.81e-05                   100%
std::shared_ptr<Foo>    : 0.000166                   591%
std::unique_ptr<Foo>    : 0.000167                   595%
std::shared_ptr<FooBase>: 0.000171                   611%
std::unique_ptr<FooBase>: 0.000171                   611%
```

The speedup appears particularly when `operator[](int i)` does not perform expensive calculations which would make the call overhead negligible.

Consider now the case where an arithmetic operation on a vector expression is too expensive to calculate each time anew (e.g. an exponential moving average). Then one needs to memoize the result, for which as before a `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double> >` is used.

```
template<typename _VectorType>
struct Average
{
    using VectorType = std::decay_t<_VectorType>;

    VectorType v;
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double> > store;

    auto operator[](int i) const
    {
        //if store[i] is filled, return it
        //otherwise calculate average and store it.
    }
};
```

In this setup, when the vector expression `v` is modified somewhere in the program, one needs to propagate that change to the dependent `Average` class (of which many copies can exists), such that `store` is recalculated -- otherwise it will contain wrong values. In this update process, however, `store` needs to be recalculated only once, regardless how many copies of the `Average` object exist.

This mix of shared-pointer and value semantics is the reason why I'm running in the somewhat confusing situation as above. My solution attempt is to enforce the same cardinality in the observer as in the updated objects -- this is the reason for the `shared_ptr<Receiver>`.

Comment: Are you consider multi-threading or not ?

Comment: I think the relationships that your design seems to represent are... confused. If `Bar` is some kind of manager of `Foo`, why does it not exist outside of the existence of the `Foo`s it manages? That is, why are the managers `shared_ptr` members of the objects they manage? Why is code external to `Foo` allowed to claim ownership of the manager (you made `Foo::bar` `public`, after all)? The design here doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @Jarod42: no multithreading up to now. But maybe later.

Comment: What @NicolBolas about rather unusual ownership and also: Why would you call `foo->update()` only once? `update` is a virtual function. You don't even know which version you'll call.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I've added a motivation for the design to the question which hopefully clears the confusion. With respect to private/public membership, I didn't care in the minimal implementation.

Comment: I added some details which on the chosen design and a perfomance measurement which -- more or less -- justifies the approach.