# Overloading the plus operator for a set of classes

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++14, type-traits, c++17

Please consider the following code snippet:

```
template<class E>
class vector_expression
{};

template<class Tuple>
class vector
    : public vector_expression<vector<Tuple>>
{};

template<class E1, class E2, class BinaryOperation>
class vector_binary_operation
    : public vector_expression<vector_binary_operation<E1, E2, BinaryOperation>>
{
public:
    vector_binary_operation(E1&& e1, E2&& e2, BinaryOperation op)
        : m_e1(e1), m_e2(e2),
          m_op(op)
    {}

private:
    E1 m_e1;
    E2 m_e2;
    BinaryOperation m_op;
};

template<class E1, class E2>
vector_binary_operation<E1, E2, std::plus<>> operator+(E1&& e1, E2&& e2) {
    return{ std::forward<E1>(e1), std::forward<E2>(e2), std::plus<>{} };
}
```

The code above ensures that `vector_binary_operation` stores references to named objects and makes copies for temporaries. The problem is the interface of `operator+`, cause it actually defines this operator for any type. What do I need to change, if I want to preserve the functionality, but only define the operator for types being or derived from `vector_expression`?

Comment: The initializer list in your constructor should better be: `m_e1(std::forward<E1>(e1)), m_e2(std::forward<E2>(e2)), m_op(std::move(op))`. Otherwise you break the perfect-forwarding chain.

Comment: @davidhigh Yes, you're right. I've copied the code from the other question and there the parameters `e1` and `e2` were const references. Thanks for noting that.

Comment: no, I'm wrong. I would be right if the constructor were a function template, something like `template<typename E1_, typename E2_> vector_binary_operation( E1_&& e1, E2_&& e2, BinaryOperation op)`. Btw, this is probably what you intended when you used the `&&`.  For more info, see [here](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)

Comment: @davidhigh With `template<typename T> using dynamic_vector = vector<std::vector<T>>;` and `dynamic_vector<double> x, y;`, the type of `e1` and `m_e1` in `x + y` will be `dynamic_vector<double>&` and `dynamic_vector<double>&`, respectively. The type of `e1` and `m_e1` in `std::move(x) + y` will be `dynamic_vector<double>&&` and `dynamic_vector<double>`, respectively. So, could you please explain in more detail what you mean?

Comment: in order to have "universal references" the template parameter type needs to be deduced. In your case, you could get problems when `E1` is a `dynamic_vector<double>`, say. The constructor then expects an rvalue-reference to `dynamic_vector<double>`, and does not allow to pass an lvalue-reference to it (which would lead to a copy to set up the member `m_e1`). There's no need to constrain the class like this.

Comment: ... so: (i) either use the constructor template two comments before, (ii) or provide overloads for both rvalue- and lvalue-refs (that grows exponentially in the number of parameters, however), (iii) or use const-references throughout and rely on your compiler's optimization features (like copy-elision).

Comment: @davidhigh (1) I cannot use a constructor template, cause I need the types `E1` and `E2` in order to declare the member variables. (2) I still don't get your argument. Why should I get problems when `E1 = dynamic_vector<double>`? Yes, the constructor then expects a `dynamic_vector<double>&&`. But since instances of `vector_binary_operation` are created by the overload operator(s) (like `operator+`) only and the operator implementation(s) ensure that a `dynamic_vector<double>&&` will be passed to the constructor whenever `E1 = dynamic_vector<double>`, I don't see any problem.

Comment: agreed, when you access it only through a specified set of functions and those meet the requirements, fine. My point was more general (--why restrict the capabilities). And just to clarify: alternative (i) above works well, the idea is to retain the class template arguments and use another different set of template parameters for the constructor ... see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a239d6f1cdec258).

Answer (score 2):

You could use SFINAE and `std::is_base_of` in the following manner:

```
template<class E1, class E2>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<vector_expression<std::decay_t<E1>>, std::decay_t<E1>>&&
                 std::is_base_of_v<vector_expression<std::decay_t<E2>>, std::decay_t<E2>>,
                 vector_binary_operation<std::decay_t<E1>, std::decay_t<E2>, std::plus<>>>
operator+(E1&& e1, E2&& e2) {
    return {
             std::forward<std::decay_t<E1>>(e1),
             std::forward<std::decay_t<E2>>(e2),
             std::plus<>{}
           };
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/aDeKwp1uhKYOReJJ)

Comment: and it needs lots of `_t` helpers to hide the `typename T::type`

Comment: @TemplateRex Then we should use the `_v` helpers too.

Comment: You don't need to use `std::plus<std::common_type_t<E1, E2>`; just `std::plus<>`.

Comment: @0xbadf00d yeah fixed that. What do yo mean with "`_v` helpers too", I'm not aware of `std::is_base_of_v`, is there such thing?

Comment: @101010 [It will be introdued with C++17](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of).

Comment: @0xbadf00d thanks for the info didn't know that this proposal will make it in C++17.

Answer (score 1):

@101010 already gave the principle. I'm extending it a bit as you asked this question also in a comment of one of my [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35629757/2412846).

As I guess you are overloading more operators than `operator+`, it's convenient to write a traits class which checks whether all passed types are `vector_expression`s:

```
template<typename ... Ts> struct is_vector_expression 
     : public std::false_type {};
template<typename T> struct is_vector_expression<T>
     : public std::is_base_of<vector_expression<std::decay_t<T> >, std::decay_t<T> >::type {};
template<typename T, typename ... Ts> struct is_vector_expression<T, Ts ...>
     : public std::integral_constant<bool, is_vector_expression<T>::value
                                        && is_vector_expression<Ts ...>::value> {};
```

When using C++17, you can also skip the variadic template stuff and use `std::conjunction`.

Next you can wrap that inside a suitable alias, so that you don't have to write `std::enable_if_t` all the time:

```
template<typename ... Ts>
using enable_for_vector_expression = std::enable_if_t<is_vector_expression<Ts...>::value>;
```

Finally, you can use that as in the following example for all your overloaded operators:

```
template<typename E1, typename E2,
         typename = enable_for_vector_expression<E1, E2> >
auto operator+(E1&& e1, E2&& e2)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: How would you implement your `is_vector_expression` trait with `std::conjunction`?

Comment: Maybe `template<typename... Ts>
  using enable_if_vector_expression_t = std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<std::is_base_of_v<vector_expression<std::decay_t<Ts>>, std::decay_t<Ts>>...>>;`?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: I would apply it on the level of `is_vector_expression` (and leave the alias as it is), but otherwise -- just in the way you wrote.

Comment: I think now that I will just use `template<class T> constexpr bool is_vector_expression_v = std::is_base_of_v<vector_expression<std::decay_t<T>>, std::decay_t<T>>;` and `class = std::enable_if_t<is_vector_expression_v<E1> && is_vector_expression_v<E2>>` as a third template argument for each operator.